# Python regex * matches occurrences only in the starting of the string

Tags: python, regex

When I use regex `p*` on string `blackpink` it returns the empty string as a match even though p is inside the string.

When I use the same regex `p*` on string `pinkpink` then it matches and returns `p`, indicating its matching only on the start of the string even though i have not specified anything of the kind.

The peculiar behavior is that, when I use `p+` on string `pink` and `blackpink`, in both cases it returns `p` , indicating it does not care if the match is in the beginning or inside a string.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: how `p+` regex in `match` would return a match with `blackpink`? I can't able to reproduce this..

Comment: how are you finding the matches...which function are you using

Comment: re.search() and then re.group(): re.search("p+", "blackpinnk").group() returns "p"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important things to understand here:

- First, `p*` matches *zero* or more, while `p+` matches *one* or more.
- Second, you will get the first match, no matter if that match is an empty string or not.
- Third, regex is greedy by default so once it found the first match it will include as many `p` as possible.

So, as a result of this,

- `p*` on `blackpink` matches the zero p at the very beginning of the string, that is `''`.
- `p*` on `pinkpink` matches the first `p` (not the second).
- `p+` on `blackpink` matches the sixth letter, the `p`, since the empty string is no longer a match because of the `+`.
- `p+` on `pinkpink` matches the first `p`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using [`re.match`](https://devdocs.io/python2/library/re#re.match) to find your pattern's matches. As you can see from the docs:

> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding `MatchObject`
>   instance.
>
> <sub>*emphasis mine*</sub>

Since, `p*` means 0 or more characters, *greedily*, the starting point of the string `blackpink` is just an empty string, `''` which satisfies your pattern. In fact, the pattern `p*` will return successful match for every empty (0-length) string between any two characters.

Comment: But however `re.match('p+', 'blackpink')` return None, instead of `p`.